# Azure upload corrupt zip, and claims I have no permissions to upload

Tags: azure, zip, unzip, corrupt

I opened azure student account, and opened a ML project on NC6 machine using azure notebooks.
I uploaded a zip that contained images, and when it finished uploading it wrote that it failed due to connection error (I do not have internet problems, and it doesn't make since it will happen 10 times at the very end) and wrote I do not have permission to upload (although I own the project, and gave myself the appropriate permissions).
Even though, it shows it uploaded the zip, but when I try to unzip it it tells me it's not a zip file - not in zip format.

When I try to unzip:

> Archive:  origin/origin.zip
> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
> a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
> latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
> the last disk(s) of this archive.

> note:  origin/origin.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive

> unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of origin/origin.zip or
> origin/origin.zip.zip, and cannot find origin/origin.zip.ZIP, period.

If someone knows the problem and could help, that would mean a lot.